# writing html content in a perl script to a file in a specific directory

Tags: perl

I have the following code in a perl/cgi script:

```
$commonContent = <<HTML;
 <font color="#CC0000"><strong>$errStr</strong></font>
 <h2 class="first">Request ID: $recId<br />(Requested by: $userInfo->[1], $userInfo->[3], $userInfo->[5])</h2>
 <h3 style="margin-bottom:16px">Website: $website</h3>
 <p><strong>Request Type: $request</strong></p>
 <p>Request Description:<br />$description</p>
 <p>Priority/Required Turnaround Time: $priority</p>
 <p>Pre-deployment review: $review</p>
 <p><strong><i>Estimated completion date for this request: $completionDate</i></strong></p>
HTML
```

I want to write the contents of the HTML to a file in a directory so I can keep it as a record.
Does anyone know how to do this? I have read the perl cookbook second edition and pro perl on this issue but its all perlish to me.

Answer (score 1):

Look at perl's [open()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

You will want to open a Filehandle, and print the variable to that filehandle.

```
open(my $fh, '>', "output.html") or die $!;
```

Comment: +1 - uses a local filehandle, the three-argument form of open, and checks for errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $myfile = '/path/to/myfile.html';
open(FILE, "> $myfile") || die "Couldn't open $myfile: $!\n";
print FILE $commonContent;
close(FILE);
```

Comment: should be "print FILE $commonContent" or else it will print to stdout.

Comment: much better, have an upvote :-)  Note to the original poster, a common Perl mistake is to try to put a comma after the FILE in the print line.  But the way dmah has it, with just a space, is exactly right.

Comment: Please don't use bareword filehandles. It is not a good practice to pass off as "normal" to beginners; it is much better for people to learn to use local lexicals right from the start.